# merge child directory to parent

Tags: linux, git, git-clone

I tried to clone a git repository, it created the directory in the wrong place.

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
/home/tendesig/public_html/respond/app/respond/
```

And want to merge the contents of the above directory with:

```
/home/tendesig/public_html/respond/
```

I tried `mv –f`, and `rsync` but that did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly of `mv -f /home/tendesig/public_html/respond/app/respond/* /home/tendesig/public_html/respond/` didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Cloning to a wrong directory is no big deal. Here's how you can fix it:

- Delete all cloned files and directories (including .git directory) and clone again to the right place
- Move all files and directories (including .git) to the right place.